# Move data from constructor to void Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I have some data values in the constructor and i want to make it usable in my voids

this is the constructor:

```
 public MitadMundo(Calculos calc)

        {

            InitializeComponent();

            string personas = calc.personas;
            string carros = calc.carros;
            string buses = calc.buses;

        }
```

and this what i want to do with the data in order to take it from the previus page to the next one

```
public async void Carrito_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Calculos calculos = new Calculos();
            calculos.personas = personas;

            CarritoPage myHomePage = new CarritoPage(calculos);
            NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(myHomePage, true);
            await Navigation.PushModalAsync(myHomePage);
        }
```

but the string is not usable in void

could you help me please i'm newly in xamarin forms.

Comment: Nothing in there makes sense. Why do you declare the variables with scope limited to the consturctor, if you want them to be avilible elsewhere? Also in your 2nd code you do not use the class `MitadMundo` at all. You use `Calculos`, wich you have not shown us

Comment: how could i declare the ariables available for all the page? inside the constructos the public modifier is not allowed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Xamarin.  This is basic C# scoping

variables declared within a method or block are scoped locally to that method/block and are not visible outside of it

```
public MitadMundo(Calculos calc)
{
    InitializeComponent();

    string personas = calc.personas;
    string carros = calc.carros;
    string buses = calc.buses;
}
```

if you want to access them from outside, declare them as class level variables

```
string personas;

public MitadMundo(Calculos calc)
{
    InitializeComponent();

    personas = calc.personas;
    string carros = calc.carros;
    string buses = calc.buses;
}
```